# Compare two date fields in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, datetime, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

in my collection each document has 2 dates, modified and sync. I would like to find those which modified > sync, or sync does not exist.

I tried

```
{'modified': { $gt : 'sync' }}
```

but it's not showing what I expected. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can not compare a field with the value of another field with the normal query matching. However, you can do this with the aggregation framework:

```
db.so.aggregate( [
    { $match: …your normal other query… },
    { $match: { $eq: [ '$modified', '$sync' ] } }
] );
```

I put …your normal other query… in there as you can make that bit use the index. So if you want to do this for only documents where the `name` field is `charles` you can do:

```
db.so.ensureIndex( { name: 1 } );
db.so.aggregate( [
    { $match: { name: 'charles' } },
    { $project: { 
        modified: 1, 
        sync: 1,
        name: 1,
        eq: { $cond: [ { $gt: [ '$modified', '$sync' ] }, 1, 0 ] } 
    } },
    { $match: { eq: 1 } }
] );
```

With the input:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("520276459bf0f0f3a6e4589c"), "modified" : 73845345, "sync" : 73234 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5202764f9bf0f0f3a6e4589d"), "modified" : 4, "sync" : 4 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5202765b9bf0f0f3a6e4589e"), "modified" : 4, "sync" : 4, "name" : "charles" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5202765e9bf0f0f3a6e4589f"), "modified" : 4, "sync" : 45, "name" : "charles" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("520276949bf0f0f3a6e458a1"), "modified" : 46, "sync" : 45, "name" : "charles" }
```

This returns:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("520276949bf0f0f3a6e458a1"),
            "modified" : 46,
            "sync" : 45,
            "name" : "charles",
            "eq" : 1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

If you want any more fields, you need to add them in the `$project`.

Comment: You should really avoid the ``$where`` variant though, as it goes through Javascript. Also, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 14):

**For MongoDB 3.6 and newer:**

The **[`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/)** operator allows the use of aggregation expressions within the query language, thus you can do the following:

```
db.test.find({ "$expr": { "$gt": ["$modified", "$sync"] } })
```

or using aggregation framework with **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "$expr": { "$gt": ["$modified", "$sync"] } } }
])
```

---

**For MongoDB 3.0+:**

You can also use the aggregation framework with the **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** pipeline operator that allows you to process the logical condition with the **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** operator and uses the special operations **[`$$KEEP`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#keep)** to "keep" the document where the logical condition is true or **[`$$PRUNE`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune)** to "remove" the document where the condition was false.

Consider running the following aggregate operation which demonstrates the above concept:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": [
            { "$gt": ["$modified", "$sync"] },
            "$$KEEP",
            "$$PRUNE"
        ]
    } }
])
```

This operation is similar to having a **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline that selects the fields in the collection and creates a new field that holds the result from the logical condition query and then a subsequent **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)**, except that **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** uses a single pipeline stage which is more efficient:

Answer (score 3):

Simply

```
db.collection.find({$where:"this.modified>this.sync"})
```

Example

```
Kobkrits-MacBook-Pro-2:~ kobkrit$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.3
connecting to: test
> db.time.insert({d1:new Date(), d2: new Date(new Date().getTime()+10000)})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.time.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("577a619493653ac93093883f"), "d1" : ISODate("2016-07-04T13:16:04.167Z"), "d2" : ISODate("2016-07-04T13:16:14.167Z") }
> db.time.find({$where:"this.d1<this.d2"})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("577a619493653ac93093883f"), "d1" : ISODate("2016-07-04T13:16:04.167Z"), "d2" : ISODate("2016-07-04T13:16:14.167Z") }
> db.time.find({$where:"this.d1>this.d2"})
> db.time.find({$where:"this.d1==this.d2"})
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript, use foreach And convert Date To toDateString()

```
db.ledgers.find({}).forEach(function(item){

    if(item.fromdate.toDateString() == item.todate.toDateString())
    {
        printjson(item)
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Right now your query is trying to return all results such that the `modified` field is greater than the word `'sync'`. Try getting rid of the quotes around `sync` and see if that fixes anything. Otherwise, I did a little research and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836434/mongodb-query-comparing-2-fields-in-same-collection-without-where). What you're trying to do just might not be possible in a single query, but you should be able to manipulate your data once you pull everything from the database.

Comment: Thanks @gr3co, I was trying to avoid aggregation but seems like the only way forward... :(

Answer (score -1):

To fix this issue without aggregation change your query to this:
`{'modified': { $gt : ISODate(this.sync) }}`