# Mongo one attribute different than the other attribute

Tags: mongodb

How do I do a MongoDB find comparing two attribute of the same document?

Like, if I have the collection "test", with this structure:

```
{a : 3, b : 4}
{a : 5, b : 5}
{a : 6, b : 6}
```

and I want to find all documents where the attribute 'a' is different than the attribute 'b', which would be the entry

```
{a : 3, b : 4}
```

.

I thought this could be accomplised by:

```
db.test.find({a : { $ne : b}})
```

but it didn't work. It gives me

```
Fri Aug  1 13:54:47 ReferenceError: b is not defined (shell):1
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108483/compare-two-date-fields-in-mongodb

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399426/mongodb-find-by-comparing-field-values

Comment: Much simpler. Thanks @MarcBaumbach

Comment: Just be careful, the accepted answer in the one I mentioned can be harsh on performance since it will perform a full table scan.

Comment: the accepted answer is wrong.  both linked questions have correct possible answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is an ad-hoc query and you don't want to keep track of different attributes (as mentioned in the entry posted by Marc B., then you can simply go with:

```
db.test.find("this.a != this.b");
```

This is going to be slow, depending on how many entries you have.

Comment: this is wrong - you are sending a string as query which is basically a noop.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky : Just tested it with my toy database and the entries proposed in here, db.test.find("this.a != this.b"); returns {a : 3, b : 4} and db.test.find("this.a == this.b"); returns {a : 5, b : 5}
{a : 6, b : 6}. I am using MongoDB shell version: 2.0.4

Comment: Okay I see - you are using a shortcut which won't work from any driver/application code - this is just sending a $where clause to the back end (you can see it in the logs: "query test.test query: { $where: "this.a==this.b" }"), making the answer a duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399426/mongodb-find-by-comparing-field-values  Aggregation is a better way to do it, as that does not involve JS.  Btw, unrelated: 2.0.4 is *really* old.

Comment: btw, this also won't work correctly for NumberLong, NumberInt and other data types that are objects...