# Doctrine MongoDB where two fields are equal

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm

How do you create a where condition in Doctrine ODM to find only documents where two fields are equal?

A document exists with two int fields `alpha` and `beta`, I want to select all documents where these two fields are equal.

I've tried the following but it returns no results:

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb
        ->field('alpha')->in($alphaIds)
        ->where('this.alpha === this.beta')
        ->sort('id', 'DESC');
    return $qb->getQuery()->execute();
```

This questions shows how to do it outside of Doctrine where alpha and beta are not equal https://stackoverflow.com/a/8433182/1283381

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Query Expressions in **[`Doctrine\MongoDB\Query\Expr`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/mongodb_odm/1.0/class-Doctrine.ODM.MongoDB.Query.Expr.html)** class to create the **[`where()`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/mongodb/1.2/source-class-Doctrine.MongoDB.Query.Expr.html#1178-1190)** expression via the **`expr()`** method as follows:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->addAnd(
    $qb->expr()     
       ->field('alpha')->in($alphaIds)
       ->where('this.alpha === this.beta')
    )
    ->sort('id', 'DESC');
return $qb->getQuery()->execute();
```

Comment: That results in the execution without any conditions i.e.  `db.DocumentName.find();`

Comment: I was just showing the salient parts, you can then return the query execution as you did `return $qb->getQuery()->execute();`

Comment: Yes, I still included `$qb->getQuery()->execute();` in the code.

Comment: It's created a condition but no results found `db.DocumentName.find({ "$and": [ { "alpha": { "$in": [ 2, 17, 3 ] }, "$where": "this.alpha === this.beta" } ] }).sort({ "_id": -1 });` I've checked document and records exist where alpha and beta = (int) 3

Answer (score 0):

If someone will be looking for an answer now:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
$qb
   ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('a.alfa', $alphaIds))
   ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('a.alpha','a.beta'))
   ->sort('id', 'DESC');
return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).