# Compare between 2 fields of a document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Consider an Invoice collection with the following documents:

```
{  "invoice_no" : "1001", "payable_amount" : 100, "paid_amount" : 50 }
{  "invoice_no" : "1002", "payable_amount" : 200, "paid_amount" : 200 }
{  "invoice_no" : "1003", "payable_amount" : 300, "paid_amount" : 150 }
{  "invoice_no" : "1004", "payable_amount" : 400, "paid_amount" : 400 }
```

Need those documents where payable_amount > paid_amount

Expected Result:

```
{  "invoice_no" : "1001", "payable_amount" : 100, "paid_amount" : 50 }
{  "invoice_no" : "1003", "payable_amount" : 300, "paid_amount" : 150 }
```

Comment: can you please look into this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433046/mongodb-query-with-fields-in-the-same-documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find plenty of examples of using the [$where operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) for this but the aggregation framework can do this for you ...

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "isPayableAmountGreater": { "$cmp": [ "$payable_amount", "$paid_amount" ] }
        }
    },
    { "$match": { "isPayableAmountGreater": 1 } }
])
```

Or, even simpler and without creating the (probably unwanted) `isPayableAmountGreater` quasi attribute:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$gt": [ "$payable_amount", "$paid_amount" ] },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }
])
```