# How to create a filter that matches a nested value against a value of the parent collection in mongodb?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

Consider the following collection:

```
{
   "_id" : (guid),
   "basePrice" : 5000,
   "productCategories" : [{
       "_id" : (Guid),
       "categoryName" : "",
       "isActive" : true,
       "products" : [{
           "_id" : (guid),
           "productCode" : "GoKart",
           "price" : 5000
       }]
   }]
}
```

I am trying to get a collection where the basePrice == price where the productCategory is active.

I tried the below c# code:

```
.Where(
   x => x.ProductCategories.Any(pc =>
               pc.IsActive &&
               pc.Products.Any(p =>
                    p.Type.ShortCode == "GoKart" &&
                    p.Price == x.BasePrice
               )
    )
)
```

Although the code looks alright, this appears to be unsupported by MongoDB.

Then I tried with Builder query. But while using ElemMatch I can't use the field property inside the filter property.

I feel I am approaching this completely wrong.
Since comparison is within the document we're having this issue. Is it possible to compare values within collection as a filter and obtain the document? I don't want to get this into memory as the records are pretty large.

Latest I have tried below code:

```
filterBuilder.And(                                
   Builders<Inventory>.Filter.ElemMatch(inv => inv.ProductCategorys,                                    
      Builders<ProductCategory>.Filter.And(                                        
         Builders<ProductCategory>.Filter.Eq(pc => pc.IsActive, true),                                        
         Builders<ProductCategory>.Filter.ElemMatch(pc => pc.Products,                                            
            Builders<Product>.Filter.Eq(p => p.ShortCode, "GoKart")
         )
      )
   ),
   Builders<Inventory>.Filter.Eq("$expr",
      Builders<Inventory>.Filter.Eq(
         "$basePrice" ,                                        
         "$ProductCategories.Products.Price"
      )
   )
);
```

This doesn't appear to work either.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using aggregation or find?  Querying one field using the value of another field in the document only works in aggregation.

Comment: Initially I was using AsQueryable, then I used the Find with builder queries. I am using sort, skip, limit in both the cases with a series of filters that are appended to one another depending on the request. So if you suggest that I use aggregation, could you kindly guide me with this as well in the context? Thank you :)

Comment: I don't do c# very well.  This answer shows how to use $expr to compare multiple fields in the same document, but it is not in c# either: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48992965/2282634

Comment: see here how to use raw mql in c#: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68397480/9492730

Comment: also, make sure that you use the last driver version before trying it

Answer (score 1):

You can unwind the arrays and do a $match to check the equality and then group them back using mongo aggregation.
Something like this :

```
[{
$match: {
  "productCategories.isActive": true,
},},{ $unwind: {
  path: "$productCategories",
  preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
},},{
$unwind: {
  path: "$productCategories.products",
  preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
}, }, {
$match: {
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      "$basePrice",
      "$productCategories.products.price",
    ],
  },
},},{
$group: {
  _id: "$productCategories.products._id",
  products: {
    $push: "$productCategories.products",
  },
  doc: {
    $first: "$$ROOT",
  },
}, }, { $replaceRoot: {
  newRoot: {
    $mergeObjects: [
      {
        products2: "$products",
      },
      "$doc",
 ],
  },
},}, {
$set: {
  "productCategories.products": "$products2",
},},{
$unset: "products2",}, { $group: {
  _id: "$productCategories._id",
  detail: {
    $first: "$$ROOT",
  },
  productCategories: {
    $addToSet: "$productCategories",
  },
},},  {    $replaceRoot: {
  newRoot: {
    $mergeObjects: [
      "$detail",
      {
        productCategories:
          "$productCategories",
      },
    ],
  },
},},]
```

Sample C# code would be like this :

```
new BsonArray{
new BsonDocument("$match", 
new BsonDocument("productCategories.isActive", true)),
new BsonDocument("$unwind", 
new BsonDocument
    {
        { "path", "$productCategories" }, 
        { "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays", true }
    }),
new BsonDocument("$unwind", 
new BsonDocument
    {
        { "path", "$productCategories.products" }, 
        { "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays", true }
    }),
new BsonDocument("$match", 
new BsonDocument("$expr", 
new BsonDocument("$eq", 
new BsonArray
            {
                "$basePrice",
                "$productCategories.products.price"
            }))),
new BsonDocument("$group", 
new BsonDocument
    {
        { "_id", "$productCategories.products._id" }, 
        { "products", 
new BsonDocument("$push", "$productCategories.products") }, 
        { "doc", 
new BsonDocument("$first", "$$ROOT") }
    }),
new BsonDocument("$replaceRoot", 
new BsonDocument("newRoot", 
new BsonDocument("$mergeObjects", 
new BsonArray
            {
                new BsonDocument("products2", "$products"),
                "$doc"
            }))),
new BsonDocument("$set", 
new BsonDocument("productCategories.products", "$products2")),
new BsonDocument("$unset", "products2"),
new BsonDocument("$group", 
new BsonDocument
    {
        { "_id", "$productCategories._id" }, 
        { "detail", 
new BsonDocument("$first", "$$ROOT") }, 
        { "productCategories", 
new BsonDocument("$addToSet", "$productCategories") }
    }),
new BsonDocument("$replaceRoot", 
new BsonDocument("newRoot", 
new BsonDocument("$mergeObjects", 
new BsonArray
            {
                "$detail",
                new BsonDocument("productCategories", "$productCategories")
            })))
```

}

Mongo Playground : https://mongoplayground.net/p/uZDZfyz7tur