# Mongoose - Query subdocument, compare elements in parent vs child

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two documents, `buyers` and `submission` (submissions are a subdocument of buyers).

```
mongoose.model('Buyer',{
    username: String,
    credit: Number,
    forms:[mongoose.model('Submission').schema]
});
```

and

```
mongoose.model('Submission',{
    title: String,
    bid: Number,
});
```

Each buyer has a `credit` attribute and each `submission` has a bid attribute. I want to build a query that will search for any submission where the bid is lower than its parent.credit

Is it possible to find based on the comparison of parent-child attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot compare two fields (be it subdocuments or not) in mongodb using normal find queries (unless you [use the $where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442453/mongodb-query-condition-on-comparing-2-fields), but be aware that it is quite slow because it executes that javascript for each document).

However, what you want is possible with the aggregation pipeline:

```
db.buyers.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$forms"},
    {$project: {
        username : 1,
        credit : 1,
        forms : 1,
        lower : {"$cond" : [{$lt: [ '$forms.bid', '$credit']}, 1, 0]}
    }},
    {$match : {lower : 1}}
]);
```

This will get you the entries where the bid is lower than the credit.