# Only update field in mongodb if it is smaller than another field

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I currently have the following query:

```
Meteor.users.update({energy: {$lt: 30}}, {$inc: {"energy": 1}}, {multi: true});
```

But I want to do the following:

```
Meteor.users.update({energy: {$lt: maxenergy}}, {$inc: {"energy": 1}}, {{multi: true});
```

Where maxenergy is another field in the document, is this possible or do I need to loop over the entire collection to do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could flip this around and make the field something like `energyLost`. Then decrement it for documents where it's greater than 0.

Comment: not sure I understand "another field in the collection" - do you mean in the same document, or do you mean sth. like max(energy) in all the collection?

Comment: Well, every user has a field called energy and a field called maxenergy.
I want to update energy only if energy is less than maxenergy.

Comment: I changed the question to say document instead of collection, since that seems to be the proper term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [$where](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator for that:

```
Meteor.users.update(
    {$where : "this.energy < this.otherFieldName"},
    {$inc: {"energy": 1}},
    {multi: true}
);
```

It's a similar problem to the one already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442453/mongodb-query-condition-on-comparing-2-fields).
Be careful though, since the JavaScript has to be executed on the server side it can be quite slow, depending on your collection size.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I did look on Google and searched on stackoverflow, but I couldn't find the answer with the terms I used.