# How to do LIKE job in MongoDB with other key's value?

Tags: regex, mongodb

In SQL i can use LIKE to express my conditions like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    book
WHERE
    publishInfo LIKE concat(publisher,'.%')
LIMIT
    100
```

It's not a perfect example, but my point is that I can put another key after LIKE to check if the target key contains text like the other key's value.

But in MongoDB, I've read official document about "$regex" method, it only tells me that I can check key's value by pure text, like this:

```
{
    publishInfo: {
        $regex: 'somePublisherNameInText\\\..+',
        $options: 'ig',
    }
}
```

How can I do the same thing in MongoDB as the example above in SQL?

Comment: You can achieve this by using `$where`, but it will be fairly slow, so it's better to avoid such things. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4443454/1377864) for details.

Comment: thanks, i will try... or i will try change my data model...