# mongoose populate pass found object reference key

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a mongoose Group schema which contains invitee (array of sub document) and currentMove, invitee also contains currentMove and I want to get document with only sub document that have same currentMove.

```
Group.findById("5a03fa29fafa645c8a399353")
.populate({
    path: 'invitee.user_id',
    select: 'currentMove',
    model:"User",
     match: {
         "currentMove":{
            $eq: "$currentMove"
        }
    }
})
```

This generates unknown currentMove Object id for match query. I'm not sure if mongoose has this functionality. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: If you need to compare the values of fields in a single document, MongoDB makes it surprisingly difficult to do. Take a look at the examples in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442453/mongodb-query-condition-on-comparing-2-fields

Answer (score 3):

In modern MongoDB releases it is far more efficient to use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) here instead of `.populate()`. Also the basic concept that you want to filter based on a comparison of fields is something that MongoDB does quite well with native operators, but it's not something you can easily transpose into `.populate()`.

In fact the only way possible to actually use with `.populate()` would be to first retrieve all results, and then use `Model.populate()` with a [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/query/where/) clause on query all whilst processing the result array with `Array.map()` in order to apply the local value of each document to the conditions to "join" on.

It's all kind of messy, and involves pulling all results from the server and filtering locally. So [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) is our best option here, where all of the "filtering" and "matching" actually takes place on the server without needing to pull unnecessary documents over the network just to obtain a result.

#### Sample Schema

You don't actually include a "schema" in your question, so we can only work with an approximation based on what parts you actually do include in the question. So my example here uses:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  currentMove: Number
})

const groupSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  topic: String,
  currentMove: Number,
  invitee: [{
    user_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    confirmed: { type: Boolean, default: false }
  }]
});
```

### Unwinding $lookup and $group

From here we have different approaches to the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) queries. The first basically involves applying [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) both before and after the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) stage. This is partly since your "reference" is an embedded field within the array, and also partly because it's actually the most efficient query form to use here with a possible "join" result that could potentially exceed the BSON limit ( 16MB for the document ) being avoided:

```
  Group.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$invitee" },
    { "$lookup": {
      "from": User.collection.name,
      "localField": "invitee.user_id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "invitee.user_id"
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$invitee.user_id" },
    { "$redact": {
      "$cond": {
        "if": { "$eq": ["$currentMove", "$invitee.user_id.currentMove"] },
        "then": "$$KEEP",
        "else": "$$PRUNE"
      }
    }},
    { "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "name": { "$first": "$name" },
      "topic": { "$first": "$topic" },
      "currentMove": { "$first": "$currentMove" },
      "invitee": { "$push": "$invitee" }
    }}
  ]);
```

The key expression here is the [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) which is processed after the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) result is returned. This allows a logical comparison of the `"currentMove"` values from both the parent document and the "joined" detail for the `User` objects.

Since we [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the array content, we use [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) with [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) to reconstruct the array ( if you must ) and select the other fields of the original document using [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/).

There are ways to examine the schema and generate such a stage, but that's not really in the scope of the question. An example can be seen on [Querying after populate in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44688386/2313887). Point being that if you want the fields returned, then you would construct this pipeline stage around using those expressions to return a document of the original shape.

### Filter $lookup result

An alternate approach where you are certain that the "unfiltered" result of the "join" will not cause the document to exceed the BSON limit is to instead make a separate target array, and then reconstruct your "joined" array content using [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/), and other array operators:

```
  Group.aggregate([
    { "$lookup": {
      "from": User.collection.name,
      "localField": "invitee.user_id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "inviteeT"
    }},
    { "$addFields": {
      "invitee": {
        "$map": {
          "input": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$inviteeT",
              "as": "i",
              "cond": { "$eq": ["$$i.currentMove","$currentMove"] }
            }
          },
          "as": "i",
          "in": {
            "_id": {
              "$arrayElemAt": [
                "$invitee._id",
                { "$indexOfArray": ["$invitee.user_id", "$$i._id"] }
              ]
            },
            "user_id": "$$i",
            "confirmed": {
              "$arrayElemAt": [
                "$invitee.confirmed",
                { "$indexOfArray": ["$invitee.user_id","$$i._id"] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
    { "$project": { "inviteeT": 0 } },
    { "$match": { "invitee.0": { "$exists": true } } }
  ]);
```

Instead of the [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) which would be filtering "documents", we use [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) here with the expression to only return those members of the target array `"inviteeT"` which share the same `"currentMove"`. Since this is just the "foreign" content, we "join" with the original array using [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and transposing the elements.

To do that "transposition" of values from the original array, we use the [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) and [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) expressions. The [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) allows us to match up the target's `"_id"` values with the `"user_id"` values in the original array and get it's "index" position. We always know this returns a real match because the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) did that part for us.

The "index" value is then supplied to [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) which similarly applies a "mapping" of the values as an array like `"$invitee.confirmed"` and returns the value matched at the same index. This is basically a "lookup" between the arrays.

Differing from the first pipeline example, we now still have the `"inviteeT"` array as well as our re-written `"invitee"` array courtesy of [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/). So one way to get rid of that is to add an additional [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and exclude the unwanted "temporary" array. And of course since we did not [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and "filter", there are still possible results with no matching array entries at all. So the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) expression uses [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to test for the `0` index being present in the array result, which means there is "at least one" result, and discards any documents with empty arrays.

### MongoDB 3.6 "sub-query"

MongoDB 3.6 makes this a bit cleaner as a new syntax for [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup) allows a more expressive "pipeline" to be given in argument to select the results returned, rather than the simplistic `"localField"` and `"foreignField"` matching.

```
  Group.aggregate([
    { "$lookup": {
      "from": User.collection.name,
      "let": {
        "ids": "$invitee._id",
        "users": "$invitee.user_id",
        "confirmed": "$invitee.confirmed",
        "currentMove": "$currentMove"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        { "$match": {
          "$expr": {
            "$and": [
              { "$in": ["$_id", "$$users"] },
              { "$eq": ["$currentMove", "$$currentMove"] }
            ]
          }
        }},
        { "$project": {
          "_id": {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$$ids",
              { "$indexOfArray": ["$$users", "$_id"] }
            ]
          },
          "user_id": "$$ROOT",
          "confirmed": {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$$confirmed",
              { "$indexOfArray": ["$$users", "$_id"] }
            ]
          }
        }}
      ],
      "as": "invitee"
    }},
    { "$match": { "invitee.0": { "$exists": true } } }
  ])
```

So there are some slightly "glitchy" things in there with the usage of mapping arrays of specific values for input due to how these are currently passed into the sub-pipeline via the `"let"` declaration. This should probably work cleaner, but on the current release candidate this is how it's actually required to be expressed in order to work.

With this new syntax the `"let"` allows us to declare "variables" from the current document which can then be referenced in the `"pipeline"` expression which will be executed in order to determine which results to return to the target array.

The [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/query/expr/) here essentially replaces the [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) or [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) conditions used before, as well as combining the "local" to "foreign" key matching which also requires us to declare such a variable. Here we mapped the `"$invitee.user_id"` values from the source document into a variable which we refer to as `"$$users"` in the rest of the expressions.

The [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) operator here is a variant for the aggregation framework which returns a boolean condition where the first argument "value" is found in the second argument "array". So this is the "foreign key" filter part.

Since this is a "pipeline", we can add a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage in addition to the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) which selected the items from the foreign collection. So again we use a similar "transposition" technique to what was described before. This then gives us control of the "shape" of the documents returned in the array, so we don't manipulate the returned array "after" the `$lookup` like we did previously.

The same case applies though, since no matter what you do here the "sub-pipeline" can of course return no results when the filter conditions do not match. So again the same [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) test is used to discard those documents.

---

So it's all pretty cool, and once you get used to the power available in the server side "join" functionality of `$lookup` you likely will never look back. Whilst the syntax is a lot more terse than the "convenience" function that `.populate()` was introduced for, the reduced traffic load, far more advanced uses and general expressiveness basically make up for that.

As a complete example, I'm also including a self contained listing that demonstrates all of these. And if you run it with a MongoDB 3.6 compatible server attached, then you will even get that demonstration as well.

Needs a recent Node.js v8.x release to run with `async/await` ( or enable in other supported ), but since that's now the LTS release you really should be running that anyway. At least install one to test :)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug',true);

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/rollgroup',
      options = { useMongoClient: true };

const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  currentMove: Number
})

const groupSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  topic: String,
  currentMove: Number,
  invitee: [{
    user_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    confirmed: { type: Boolean, default: false }
  }]
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
const Group = mongoose.model('Group', groupSchema);

function log(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2))
}

(async function() {

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri,options);

    let { version } = await conn.db.admin().command({'buildInfo': 1});

    // Clean data
    await Promise.all(
      Object.entries(conn.models).map(([k,m]) => m.remove() )
    );

    // Add some users
    let users = await User.insertMany([
      { name: 'Bill', currentMove: 1 },
      { name: 'Ted', currentMove: 2 },
      { name: 'Fred', currentMove: 3 },
      { name: 'Sally', currentMove: 4 },
      { name: 'Harry', currentMove: 5 }
    ]);

    await Group.create({
      name: 'Group1',
      topic: 'This stuff',
      currentMove: 3,
      invitee: users.map( u =>
        ({ user_id: u._id, confirmed: (u.currentMove === 3) })
      )
    });

    await (async function() {
      console.log('Unwinding example');
      let result = await Group.aggregate([
        { "$unwind": "$invitee" },
        { "$lookup": {
          "from": User.collection.name,
          "localField": "invitee.user_id",
          "foreignField": "_id",
          "as": "invitee.user_id"
        }},
        { "$unwind": "$invitee.user_id" },
        { "$redact": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": { "$eq": ["$currentMove", "$invitee.user_id.currentMove"] },
            "then": "$$KEEP",
            "else": "$$PRUNE"
          }
        }},
        { "$group": {
          "_id": "$_id",
          "name": { "$first": "$name" },
          "topic": { "$first": "$topic" },
          "currentMove": { "$first": "$currentMove" },
          "invitee": { "$push": "$invitee" }
        }}
      ]);

      log(result);

    })();

    await (async function() {
      console.log('Using $filter example');
      let result = await Group.aggregate([
        { "$lookup": {
          "from": User.collection.name,
          "localField": "invitee.user_id",
          "foreignField": "_id",
          "as": "inviteeT"
        }},
        { "$addFields": {
          "invitee": {
            "$map": {
              "input": {
                "$filter": {
                  "input": "$inviteeT",
                  "as": "i",
                  "cond": { "$eq": ["$$i.currentMove","$currentMove"] }
                }
              },
              "as": "i",
              "in": {
                "_id": {
                  "$arrayElemAt": [
                    "$invitee._id",
                    { "$indexOfArray": ["$invitee.user_id", "$$i._id"] }
                  ]
                },
                "user_id": "$$i",
                "confirmed": {
                  "$arrayElemAt": [
                    "$invitee.confirmed",
                    { "$indexOfArray": ["$invitee.user_id","$$i._id"] }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }},
        { "$project": { "inviteeT": 0 } },
        { "$match": { "invitee.0": { "$exists": true } } }
      ]);

      log(result);

    })();

    await (async function() {
      if (parseFloat(version.match(/\d\.\d/)[0]) >= 3.6) {
        console.log('New $lookup example. Yay!');
        let result = await Group.collection.aggregate([
          { "$lookup": {
            "from": User.collection.name,
            "let": {
              "ids": "$invitee._id",
              "users": "$invitee.user_id",
              "confirmed": "$invitee.confirmed",
              "currentMove": "$currentMove"
            },
            "pipeline": [
              { "$match": {
                "$expr": {
                  "$and": [
                    { "$in": ["$_id", "$$users"] },
                    { "$eq": ["$currentMove", "$$currentMove"] }
                  ]
                }
              }},
              { "$project": {
                "_id": {
                  "$arrayElemAt": [
                    "$$ids",
                    { "$indexOfArray": ["$$users", "$_id"] }
                  ]
                },
                "user_id": "$$ROOT",
                "confirmed": {
                  "$arrayElemAt": [
                    "$$confirmed",
                    { "$indexOfArray": ["$$users", "$_id"] }
                  ]
                }
              }}
            ],
            "as": "invitee"
          }},
          { "$match": { "invitee.0": { "$exists": true } } }
        ]).toArray();

        log(result);

      }
    })();

    await (async function() {
      console.log("Horrible populate example :(");

      let results = await Group.find();

       results = await Promise.all(
        results.map( r =>
          User.populate(r,{
            path: 'invitee.user_id',
            match: { "$where": `this.currentMove === ${r.currentMove}` }
          })
        )
      );

      console.log("All members still there");
      log(results);

      // Then we clean it for null values

      results = results.map( r =>
        Object.assign(r,{
          invitee: r.invitee.filter(i => i.user_id !== null)
        })
      );

      console.log("Now they are filtered");
      log(results);

    })();


  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }

})()
```

Gives the output for each example as:

```
Mongoose: users.remove({}, {})
Mongoose: groups.remove({}, {})
Mongoose: users.insertMany([ { __v: 0, name: 'Bill', currentMove: 1, _id: 5a0afda01643cf41789e500a }, { __v: 0, name: 'Ted', currentMove: 2, _id: 5a0afda01643cf41789e500b }, { __v: 0, name: 'Fred', currentMove: 3, _id: 5a0afda01643cf41789e500c }, { __v: 0, name: 'Sally', currentMove: 4, _id: 5a0afda01643cf41789e500d }, { __v: 0, name: 'Harry', currentMove: 5, _id: 5a0afda01643cf41789e500e } ], {})
Mongoose: groups.insert({ name: 'Group1', topic: 'This stuff', currentMove: 3, _id: ObjectId("5a0afda01643cf41789e500f"), invitee: [ { user_id: ObjectId("5a0afda01643cf41789e500a"), _id: ObjectId("5a0afda01643cf41789e5014"), confirmed: false }, { user_id: ObjectId("5a0afda01643cf41789e500b"), _id: ObjectId("5a0afda01643cf41789e5013"), confirmed: false }, { user_id: ObjectId("5a0afda01643cf41789e500c"), _id: ObjectId("5a0afda01643cf41789e5012"), confirmed: true }, { user_id: ObjectId("5a0afda01643cf41789e500d"), _id: ObjectId("5a0afda01643cf41789e5011"), confirmed: false }, { user_id: ObjectId("5a0afda01643cf41789e500e"), _id: ObjectId("5a0afda01643cf41789e5010"), confirmed: false } ], __v: 0 })
Unwinding example
Mongoose: groups.aggregate([ { '$unwind': '$invitee' }, { '$lookup': { from: 'users', localField: 'invitee.user_id', foreignField: '_id', as: 'invitee.user_id' } }, { '$unwind': '$invitee.user_id' }, { '$redact': { '$cond': { if: { '$eq': [ '$currentMove', '$invitee.user_id.currentMove' ] }, then: '$$KEEP', else: '$$PRUNE' } } }, { '$group': { _id: '$_id', name: { '$first': '$name' }, topic: { '$first': '$topic' }, currentMove: { '$first': '$currentMove' }, invitee: { '$push': '$invitee' } } } ], {})
[
  {
    "_id": "5a0afda01643cf41789e500f",
    "name": "Group1",
    "topic": "This stuff",
    "currentMove": 3,
    "invitee": [
      {
        "user_id": {
          "_id": "5a0afda01643cf41789e500c",
          "__v": 0,
          "name": "Fred",
          "currentMove": 3
        },
        "_id": "5a0afda01643cf41789e5012",
        "confirmed": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
Using $filter example
Mongoose: groups.aggregate([ { '$lookup': { from: 'users', localField: 'invitee.user_id', foreignField: '_id', as: 'inviteeT' } }, { '$addFields': { invitee: { '$map': { input: { '$filter': { input: '$inviteeT', as: 'i', cond: { '$eq': [ '$$i.currentMove', '$currentMove' ] } } }, as: 'i', in: { _id: { '$arrayElemAt': [ '$invitee._id', { '$indexOfArray': [ '$invitee.user_id', '$$i._id' ] } ] }, user_id: '$$i', confirmed: { '$arrayElemAt': [ '$invitee.confirmed', { '$indexOfArray': [ '$invitee.user_id', '$$i._id' ] } ] } } } } } }, { '$project': { inviteeT: 0 } }, { '$match': { 'invitee.0': { '$exists': true } } } ], {})
[
  {
    "_id": "5a0afda01643cf41789e500f",
    "name": "Group1",
    "topic": "This stuff",
    "currentMove": 3,
    "invitee": [
      {
        "_id": "5a0afda01643cf41789e5012",
        "user_id": {
          "_id": "5a0afda01643cf41789e500c",
          "__v": 0,
          "name": "Fred",
          "currentMove": 3
        },
        "confirmed": true
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0
  }
]
New $lookup example. Yay!
Mongoose: groups.aggregate([ { '$lookup': { from: 'users', let: { ids: '$invitee._id', users: '$invitee.user_id', confirmed: '$invitee.confirmed', currentMove: '$currentMove' }, pipeline: [ { '$match': { '$expr': { '$and': [ { '$in': [ '$_id', '$$users' ] }, { '$eq': [ '$currentMove', '$$currentMove' ] } ] } } }, { '$project': { _id: { '$arrayElemAt': [ '$$ids', { '$indexOfArray': [ '$$users', '$_id' ] } ] }, user_id: '$$ROOT', confirmed: { '$arrayElemAt': [ '$$confirmed', { '$indexOfArray': [ '$$users', '$_id' ] } ] } } } ], as: 'invitee' } }, { '$match': { 'invitee.0': { '$exists': true } } } ])
[
  {
    "_id": "5a0afda01643cf41789e500f",
    "name": "Group1",
    "topic": "This stuff",
    "currentMove": 3,
    "invitee": [
      {
        "_id": "5a0afda01643cf41789e5012",
        "user_id": {
          "_id": "5a0afda01643cf41789e500c",
          "__v": 0,
          "name": "Fred",
          "currentMove": 3
        },
        "confirmed": true
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0
  }
]
Horrible populate example :(
Mongoose: groups.find({}, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: users.find({ _id: { '$in': [ ObjectId("5a0afda01643cf41789e500a"), ObjectId("5a0afda01643cf41789e500b"), ObjectId("5a0afda01643cf41789e500c"), ObjectId("5a0afda01643cf41789e500d"), ObjectId("5a0afda01643cf41789e500e") ] }, '$where': 'this.currentMove === 3' }, { fields: {} })
All members still there
[
  {
    "_id": "5a0afda01643cf41789e500f",
    "name": "Group1",
    "topic": "This stuff",
    "currentMove": 3,
    "__v": 0,
    "invitee": [
      {
        "user_id": null,
        "_id": "5a0afda01643cf41789e5014",
        "confirmed": false
      },
      {
        "user_id": null,
        "_id": "5a0afda01643cf41789e5013",
        "confirmed": false
      },
      {
        "user_id": {
          "_id": "5a0afda01643cf41789e500c",
          "__v": 0,
          "name": "Fred",
          "currentMove": 3
        },
        "_id": "5a0afda01643cf41789e5012",
        "confirmed": true
      },
      {
        "user_id": null,
        "_id": "5a0afda01643cf41789e5011",
        "confirmed": false
      },
      {
        "user_id": null,
        "_id": "5a0afda01643cf41789e5010",
        "confirmed": false
      }
    ]
  }
]
Now they are filtered
[
  {
    "_id": "5a0afda01643cf41789e500f",
    "name": "Group1",
    "topic": "This stuff",
    "currentMove": 3,
    "__v": 0,
    "invitee": [
      {
        "user_id": {
          "_id": "5a0afda01643cf41789e500c",
          "__v": 0,
          "name": "Fred",
          "currentMove": 3
        },
        "_id": "5a0afda01643cf41789e5012",
        "confirmed": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

---

## Using populate()

So using `.populate()` here is actually pretty horrible. Sure it looks like less, but it's actually doing a lot of things that simply are not needed, and all because the "join" does not happen on the server:

```
   // Note that we cannot populate "here" since we need the returned value
   let results = await Group.find();

   // The value is only in context as we use `Array.map()` to process each result
   results = await Promise.all(
    results.map( r =>
      User.populate(r,{
        path: 'invitee.user_id',
        match: { "$where": `this.currentMove === ${r.currentMove}` }
      })
    )
  );

  console.log("All members still there");
  log(results);

  // Then we clean it for null values

  results = results.map( r =>
    Object.assign(r,{
      invitee: r.invitee.filter(i => i.user_id !== null)
    })
  );

  console.log("Now they are filtered");
  log(results);
```

So I also included that in the output above, as well as the whole code listing.

The problem becomes evident as you cannot "chain" the populate directly to the first query. You actually need to return the documents ( potentially ALL of them ) in order to use the current document value in a subsequent populate. And this MUST be processed for each document returned.

Not only that but `populate()` is NOT going to "filter" the array to only those which match, even with the query condition. All it does is set's the unmatched elements to `null`:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5a0afa889f9f7e4064d8794d",
    "name": "Group1",
    "topic": "This stuff",
    "currentMove": 3,
    "__v": 0,
    "invitee": [
      {
        "user_id": null,
        "_id": "5a0afa889f9f7e4064d87952",
        "confirmed": false
      },
      {
        "user_id": null,
        "_id": "5a0afa889f9f7e4064d87951",
        "confirmed": false
      },
      {
        "user_id": {
          "_id": "5a0afa889f9f7e4064d8794a",
          "__v": 0,
          "name": "Fred",
          "currentMove": 3
        },
        "_id": "5a0afa889f9f7e4064d87950",
        "confirmed": true
      },
      {
        "user_id": null,
        "_id": "5a0afa889f9f7e4064d8794f",
        "confirmed": false
      },
      {
        "user_id": null,
        "_id": "5a0afa889f9f7e4064d8794e",
        "confirmed": false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This then needs an `Array.filter()` to be processed again for "each" document returned, which can finally remove the unwanted array items and give you the same result the other aggregation queries are doing.

So it's "really wasteful" and just not a good way to do things. Little point in having a database, when you're actually doing the majority of processing on the server. In fact, we may have well simply returned the populated result and then run an `Array.filter()` in order to remove the unwanted entries.

This is just not how you write fast and effective code. So the example here is sometimes "what looks simple" is actually doing a lot more damage than good.

Comment: great explaination thanks @neil but i'm looking for cleaner way to write query in mongoose with compromising performance. i saw mongoose takes _ids of results found then pass them to populate query seperatly. if it collect _ids after steam all result then why should not allow passing other key to populate. i think it is not facilitated by mongoose yet

Comment: @shivshankar You need to really read this and understand. What you might percieve as "clean" just is NOT the case. The core problem here is that your "condition" where you want the `currentMove` means that the way `.populate()` actually works, it is simply "not possible" for mongoose to not return results of the parent with "no matching children". This is "why" you join on the server. It's a lot more efficient even if it "appears" more terse. Also look at the other linked answer within the answer body here which shows a method for making much of the generation "automatic".

Comment: @shivshankar Take all the time you need. The longer this sits up for attention the better, since more people really should see how this should really be handled. Also added `populate()` to demonstrate the problems involved. The gory details on why it's not a great idea are also covered on [Mongoose Query Aftter Populate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303294/querying-after-populate-in-mongoose/) where I have also added a method using `$lookup` and all about how to automate the pipeline generation ( in sample case, if not all cases complete )