# How to perform $match with second collection using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, mongoose

I have to display the message from start date to end date ..Once end date is over ,message should disable..I have tried to match but am not getting the values..Kindly help me in this issue..Thanks in Advance

```
mongo.notification.find({'clienttoken' : req.body.clienttoken},function(err,response){
        if (err) throw err
        console.log(response)
           console.log("get Request from Client")
             mongo.user.aggregate([
                {
                    $lookup:{
                        from:"notifications",
                        localField:"_id",
                        foreignField:"user_id",
                        as:"PersonName"
                            }
                },
                {
                    $match: {'clienttoken' : req.body.clienttoken , 'end_date':  { $gt:  'start_date', $lt:  'end_date'}
                }
                },
                {
                    $unwind:'$PersonName'
                },
                {
                "$project":{
                    "username":"$username",
                    "fname":"$fname",
                    "userid":"$_id",
                    "email":"$email",
                    "clienttoken" : "$clienttoken",
                    "message":"$PersonName.message",
                    "end_date" : "$PersonName.end_date",
                   "start_date":  "$PersonName.start_date"  
                    }
                }
                ]).exec(function(err, clientmsg){
                if (err) throw err; 
                res.json(clientmsg)


            });
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDb query condition on comparing 2 fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442453/mongodb-query-condition-on-comparing-2-fields)

Comment: I am using 3.2 MongoDB and i am having start and end date in second collection

Comment: Yes, indeed, the previous answer doesn't provide copy and paste solution, but please put some effort in it. Read and comprehend all answers of the previous question, not only the accepted one. Number of collections doesn't matter.  Aggregation is a pipeline, it works with stages. Collections come in play only on first stage, lookup stages, and output. All other stages take output of the previous one as input, and it doesn't matter from how many collections it came. `$cmp` is available since 2.4, if not earlier. With 3.2 you can't use `$addField`, but it is not critical and can be worked around

Comment: Thank you for your response.. ll try