# Mongo Db array two Key Compare

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have collection like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5adc0f2b2fabb719699ff257"),
    "name" : "Anil",
    "mobile" : 8108582645,
    "packages" : [
        {
            "totalAmount" : 6000,
            "purchaseDate" : ISODate("2018-04-22T04:00:00Z"),
            "expiryDate" : ISODate("2018-10-22T04:00:00Z"),
            "name" : "six month",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5adc0f2b2fabb719699ff258"),
            "isActive" : true,
            "paid" : 1000
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5adc0f862fabb719699ff259"),
    "name" : "Mahesh",
    "mobile" : 9877110154,
    "packages" : [
        {
            "name" : "six month",
            "expiryDate" : ISODate("2018-10-22T04:00:00Z"),
            "purchaseDate" : ISODate("2018-04-22T04:00:00Z"),
            "totalAmount" : 6000,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5adc0fa72fabb719699ff25b"),
            "isActive" : true,
            "paid" : null
        }
    ]
}
```

and I want all collection where **package.paid === package.totalAmount**

in Sql we do like this:

```
select * 
from packages
where paid=total;
```

in short I want all user who paid for there package.

Comment: use aggregate pipeline and in match query compare with paid:'$total'

Comment: @RatanUdayKumar can u give a small code snippet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442453/mongodb-query-condition-on-comparing-2-fields - here only example given only on simple document not on an array