# mongodb find all document in which one field contains another field

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have documents in mongodb like:

```
{
  "legal_name": "Roshan Bhandari",
  "first_name": "Roshan"
}
```

In sql for such data I would do:

```
Select * from mytable where first_name not like '%' + LOWER([legal_name]) + '%'
```

In mongodb I tried following:

```
db.mytable.find({'$expr': {'first_name':{'$nin': 'legal_name'}})
```

But it didnt work. What would be approriate solution for this?

Comment: `legal_name` should be in quotes

Comment: @zmbq that is not the case, please refer to sql I wrote.

Comment: @VaghaniJanak I do not want string comparison, I want 2 column comparison

Comment: db.mytable.find({ $where : "this.first_name != this.legal_name" })

Comment: Please refers below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442453/mongodb-query-condition-on-comparing-2-fields

Comment: You can do something like this https://mongoplayground.net/p/cOxOZNLvRRx