# How to select an object in array that have an item equal to a field of the owning document?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have document like this one:

```
{
 MyField1: 'A'
 MyArray: [
  {
   MyArrayField1 = 'C';
   MyArrayField2 = 25;
  },
  {
   MyArrayField1 = 'A';
   MyArrayField2 = 26;
  }
]
```

How can I select all documents that contain in `MyArray` an object with `MyArrayField1 = MyField1` AND `MyArrayField2 = 26;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per:
[MongoDb query condition on comparing 2 fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442453/mongodb-query-condition-on-comparing-2-fields)

You can use [`expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) like so:

```
db.find({$and: [{$expr: {$eq: ["$MyArray.MyArrayField1", "$MyField1"]}}, {"MyArray.MyArrayField2": 26}]})
```