# MongoDB match subfield in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following issue when I try to match elements in an array based on the value in one of the array subfields.

Example document structure:

```
{
    "A" : {
        "C" : "abc"
    },
    "B" : [ 
        {
            "C" : "def"
        }, 
        {
            "C" : "ghi"
        }, 
        {
            "C" : "jkl"
        }, 
        {
            "C" : "abc"
        }
    ]
}
```

Example result document:

```
{
    "A" : {
        "C" : "abc"
    },
    "B" : [ 
        {
            "C" : "abc"
        }
    ]
}
```

My attempt:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {'$match': {
        'B.C': 'A.C'
        }},
    {'$project': {
        'A.C': 1,
        'B.C': 1
        }}
])
```

Where am I making an error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$filter`  aggregation here

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "B": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$B",
        "cond": { "$eq": ["$$this.C", "$A.C"] }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! Would you mind explaining the issue with the way I attempted to do it? That is, using `$match`.

Comment: You have completely misunderstood the aggregation here. `$match` `'B.C': 'A.C'` doesn't make any sense. Even if you want to [match the two fields from the document you have to use `$expr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442453/mongodb-query-condition-on-comparing-2-fields). And if you want to get an updated array so basically you need some array operator(as `$filter` here) to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop into a sub array by using the qry part

```
mainarray.subarray name

eg : B.C
```