# MongoDB match array based on document value

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, match, projection

Let's say I have the following document structure:

```
{
  "A": {
    "_id": "ID0"
  },
  "B": [
    "a": {
      "_id": "ID0",
      "field": "X"
    },
    "b": {
      "_id": "ID1",
      "field": "Y"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to project `B` matched with the `_id` in `A`. The end result would be:

```
{
  "B": [
    "a": {
      "_id": "ID0",
      "field": "X"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried the following but apparently I'm doing something wrong:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {"B._id": "$A._id"}},
  {$project: {"B": 1}}
])
```

Comment: @Ashh that wasn't really my question. What I want to do is to match based on one of the document fields instead of an explicit condition.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48410935/7510657

Comment: Thanks! Will check it out.