# MongoDB match array based on document value rather than explicit condition

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, match, projection

Let's say I have the following document structure:

```
{
  "A": {
    "_id": "ID0"
  },
  "B": [
    {
      "_id": "ID0",
      "field": "X"
    },
    {
      "_id": "ID1",
      "field": "Y"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to project `B` matched with the `_id` in `A`. The end result would be:

```
{
  "B": [
    {
      "_id": "ID0",
      "field": "X"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried the following but apparently I'm doing something wrong. Is it possible to match based on a document filed rather than an explicit condition?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {"B._id": "$A._id"}},
  {$project: {"B": 1}}
])
```

Comment: your document structure is not a valid json...

Comment: I just made up that example so I might have missed a character somewhere. Feel free to point it out!

Comment: B is an array... 'a' and 'b' are fields of same object? two different objects? Not a typo, but a structure issue

Comment: `a` and `b` are documents inside the array `B`.

Comment: "B": [
    {"a": {
      "_id": "ID0",
      "field": "X"
    }},
   { "b": {
      "_id": "ID1",
      "field": "Y"
    }}
  ]

Comment: or  "B": [
    {
      "_id": "ID0",
      "field": "X"
    },
    {
      "_id": "ID1",
      "field": "Y"
    }
  ]

Comment: Aah now I see, I'll update! Thanks :)

Comment: "B": [
    "a": {
      "_id": "ID0",
      "field": "X"
    }
  ] is not valid! choose a valid structure between the 2 previous

Comment: Yep, I've updated the Q.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB match array based on document value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61223895/mongodb-match-array-based-on-document-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $filter aggregation operator to achieve this :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "B": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$B",
          as: "arr",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$A._id",
              "$$arr._id"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Test it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KcMu5EXrd2T)