# How to Find And Update With Mongoose When a Field is Greater / Lesser Than Other

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to update a field in my MongoDB database with Mongoose if the new value of that field wouldn't be greater than another field. Here is my code:

```
Training.findOneAndUpdate(
    { date: dateStringForDB, startHour: retrievedRequest.body.trainingStartHour },
    { $push: { participants: retrievedRequest.session.loggedInPhoneNumber }, $inc: { currentQuota: +1 } },
    (err, doc, updateResponse) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error while updating training ", err);
        return;
      }

      retrievedResponse.redirect("/schedule");
    }
  );
```

What I want to do is increment the value of `currentQuota` only if value of 'currentQuota' is smaller than another field's (`initialQuota`) value. Is there a way to do it with `findOneAndUpdate` method or shall I call `find` method first and then `update`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're trying to compare two fields within the same document, you can try this in your filter query object. `{ date: dateStringForDB, startHour: retrievedRequest.body.trainingStartHour, $expr: { $gt:["$initialQuota", "$currentQuota"] } }`. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442453/mongodb-query-condition-on-comparing-2-fields/48410935#48410935

Comment: Hey @v1shva! That is exactly what I was looking for - thanks a lot, been a great help.

Comment: Happy to help, I added a answer with additional docs, if you need it.

Comment: var query = { owner: 'bingo', weight: { $lt: 55 } };
    model = await Dummy.findOne(query);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare two fields within the same document using `$expr` in your query object.

```
Training.findOneAndUpdate(
    { date: dateStringForDB, startHour: retrievedRequest.body.trainingStartHour, $expr: { $gt:["$initialQuota", "$currentQuota"] } },
    { $push: { participants: retrievedRequest.session.loggedInPhoneNumber }, $inc: { currentQuota: +1 } },
    (err, doc, updateResponse) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error while updating training ", err);
        return;
      }

      retrievedResponse.redirect("/schedule");
    }
  );
```

> Refer to this for more info:
> [MongoDb query condition on comparing 2 fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442453/mongodb-query-condition-on-comparing-2-fields/48410935#48410935)
>
> Mongodb docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/