# Dynamic mongodb operation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation, mongodb-compass

I'm trying to get all documents that their health is less than their maxHealth but I don't find any success and I don't find any information online, please assist.

This is the code I used

```
/**
 * query: The query in MQL.
 */
{
  health: {
    $lt: '$maxHealth'
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try comparing the two fields in the `$match` stage using the [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) operator.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I couldn't find a way

Comment: [MongoDb query condition on comparing 2 fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442453/mongodb-query-condition-on-comparing-2-fields). Note the two fields are within the same document.