# I want to find documents in mongodb database using field value as a variable

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

In my Below code , Getting syntax error in line no : 2

I am using only one integer variable `today`

```
async def get_users(self):
     today = 5
     return self.col.find({'prexdate': {$gte: int(today)}}) #in this line getting a syntax error
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDb query condition on comparing 2 fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442453/mongodb-query-condition-on-comparing-2-fields)

Answer (score 0):

your field is **'prexdate':**  
try this instead **prexdate:**

Here is also a link https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Comment: This is not an helpful answer, as your suggestion will not change anything...mongodb allows keys inside a query to be with or without quotes