# mongodb aggregation where document field is less than another field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Using mongoose, I'm trying to make a query that searches for tasks where `timeSpent` is greater than `timeBilled`.

Task schema:

```js
const myTaskSchema = new Schema({
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  timeSpent: { type: Number },
  timeBilled: { type: Number }
})
```

The query I've tried:

```js
   myTaskSchema.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          timeSpent: { $gt: '$timeBilled' }
        }
      }
    ])
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data)
      })
```

But I'm getting zero results (I know there should be results)

NOTE: Not every task has a `timeSpent` or `timeBilled`.field if that matters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDb query condition on comparing 2 fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442453/mongodb-query-condition-on-comparing-2-fields)

Comment: that thread lead me to a solution.  I looks sloppy and I'd be open to other solutions but I'll post my solution here.

Answer (score 1):

here is my dirty solution. It'd be nice if I didnt have to add a field but this gets me where I want to be.

```js
 myTaskSchema.aggregate([
      {
        $addFields: {
          needToBill: { $gt: ['$timeSpent', '$timeBilled'] }
        }
      },
      {
        $match: {
          needToBill: true
        }
      },
      {
        $project: {
          timeSpent: 1,
          timeBilled: 1
        }
      }
    
    ])
```

Comment: You can do something simpler like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XM4PnX1akyi)