# How to filter objects with same values in different properites in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-compass

I have collection with 2 properties "from_id", "chat_id". I want to filter objects with same values in this fields.

Unfortunatelly, `from_id: { $ne: '$chat_id' }` doen't works.
[image]

Advice me, please how to exclude such objects.

Comment: You need [`$expr`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) operator in order to compare different fields.

Comment: $expr: { $ne: ["$from_id", "$chat_id"]

thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDb query condition on comparing 2 fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442453/mongodb-query-condition-on-comparing-2-fields)